# How can I detect upper body from shoulder to navel point in Flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, augmented-reality

I have created virtual dressing Android app for  project but i am facing one issues regarding dress fitting on upper body from shoulder to navel point, i have tried many searches about that issues, but can't find proper solution yet.
How i can solve this?

Comment: Please share your current code.

Comment: @VictorEronmosele sir I don't have idea how to integrate such type of code into my project, I still don't have created that code, kindly help me if there's any kind of API or other piece of code, so i can add it to my code for virtual dressing,
Thankyou sir.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.